# Is it kinda true to say "All Magnets are Electromagnets?"

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

Just had a physics test recently and was stumped by this one question and I have been thinking about it for a week but can't seem to get in down

Q : Explain why is kinda true to say "All magnets are electromagnets"

My answer(given 2/10) : Magnetic fields are created by moving or changing electric fields and an electromagnet is just moving electric charges through a wire which acts like a magnet. Since a moving electric field is essentially like a current, we can pretty much say its an electromagnet since its moving electric field through a medium.

Comment: Was it supposed to involve bound vs. free currents?

Comment: no idea professor said more valuable to figure it out on out own and wouldnt tell us

Comment: Well, the first part of your statement is easily misinterpreted, I guess. There aren't any significant electric fields emanating from a permanent magnet. In this case, moving _charges_ generate a magnetic field, not moving electric fields.

Comment: So is my answer technically right? One of my peers said that F = BIL might have something to do with it

Comment: The problem for me is I disagree with the premise of the question. In ordinary usage, electromagnets refer to objects that have a nontrivial _free_ current flowing through them, which would disqualify permanent magnets. Maybe someone who disagrees with me could interpret this question better.

Comment: Unless you give a precise definition of "electromagnet", this seems to be a question about guessing what your teacher meant by "electromagnet", not about physics.

Answer (score 0):

There are [two kinds of magnets](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/elemag.html): permanent magnets (on the right), and electromagnets.

[image: magnets]

The question really is asking  if  the permanent magnet on the right, arises because   a large number of small electromagnets at the atomic level add up to the permanent field.  At first level the answer is yes. There is a permanent magnetic field in the iron atoms that compose a permanent magnet, oriented in the same direction to build up a macroscopic magnetic field.

There is a [magnetic dipole moment for electron orbits](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/orbmag.html#c2) , and under special conditions the atoms can display a magnetic moment built up by the individual electron orbit magnetic dipoles.

It is a first level answer because quantum mechanics enters, and the *intrinsic  magnetic dipole moment of the electron, which dominates.*

> [The spin of the electrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferromagnetism#Origin_of_magnetism) in atoms is the main source of ferromagnetism, *although there is also a contribution from the orbital angular momentum* of the electron about the nucleus. When these magnetic dipoles in a piece of matter are aligned, (point in the same direction) their individually tiny magnetic fields add together to create a much larger macroscopic field.

italics mine.

The part of the permanent magnet coming from the orbits of the electrons can be thought to come from moving charges the same as electromagnets.

BUT the electron's magnetic dipole moment is intrinsic, as it is a point particle in the particle data of the [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model), not made up of "moving" composites.

So the title statement

> Is it kinda true to say “All Magnets are Electromagnets?”

is partially  true. Permanent magnets mostly display  the addition of electron intrinsic magnetic dipole moments, which at present theories are not generated by rotating charge so as to be modeled as electromagnets. Only the orbital contribution has to do with rotating charges , and could be thought as an electromagnet.

Comment: All you have said here is that any permanent magnet can be replicated as an electromagnet. How does this prove that permanent magnets _are_ electromagnets?

Comment: @probably_someone I am saying that most of the permanent magnet magnetic field comes from the intrinsic magnetic moment of the electrons. A small part comes from the motion (orbits) of electrons around the nucleus. Motion of charges in orbits creates small electromagnets. Is my grammar or syntax misleading?